# Why can't I add class to this html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add this the active class to the element when the user clicks it. Why does it not work? Is there something wrong with the syntax?

HTML code:

```
  <div class="accordion">
            <h3>a</h3>
            <p class="active">b</p>

            <h3>a</h3>
            <p>b</p>

            <h3>b</h3>
            <p>b</p>

            <h3>b</h3>
            <p>b</p>
        </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('div.accordion').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

What i wanna do is when the user clicks h3, thats when it sets the p tag below it the active class

Comment: Yo, bruv - it does add the class in the element you are setting `:)` demo here might help: http://jsfiddle.net/U7LH2/

Comment: it's working fine, check here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eL3Uf/2/)

Comment: @Unknown Yes I'm trying to add it to the p tag.

Comment: What do you think `this` refers to inside your event handler? You are binding the handler to `div.accordion` and that's where the class is added to.

Comment: Next time, make sure you are explaining the problem properly from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind click event to `H3` elements. Also make sure you remove previously active elements:

```
var $h3 = $('.accordion > h3').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $h3.next('p').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next('p').addClass('active');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2DB37/

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to add the active class to the p tag.

You forgot to add a click event to the p tag:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('div.accordion h3').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('p').addClass("active");
    });

});
```

Comment: What I wanna do is when the user clicks h3, thats when it sets the p tag below it the active class.

Answer (score 0):

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eL3Uf/3/)

change jQuery to like this

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('div.accordion p').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

---

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2qn2y/)

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('div.accordion h3').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: What I wanna do is when the user clicks h3, thats when it sets the p tag below it the active class